# Why/When is Executions.getCurrent() null? - How to debug it?

Tags: zk

I am trying to understand what **zk.ui.Executions.getCurrent() is and when it is null**. I got a log error message saying "Server Push cannot be started without execution" during an async operation and have tracked it down to Executions.getCurrent() being null.

I am using ZK 8.5.0. with Spring framework 4 and I also have a multithread application. It is really difficult to post code but I can tell you that this happens during a start() method (runs before the run() method) inside a class that implements the Runnable Interface. I tried to debug it line by line - Executions.getCurrent() always has a value. I tried to somehow force it to become null by closing the tab or refreshing the page while the async operation was ongoing but had no luck. It resulted in a different error, something about not finding the desktop with the given id.
I should add here the relevant stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Server Push cannot be started without execution
      at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.DesktopImpl.enableServerPush0(DesktopImpl.java:1510)
      at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.DesktopImpl.enableServerPush(DesktopImpl.java:1470)
      at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.DesktopImpl.enableServerPush(DesktopImpl.java:1455)
      at c.p.t.e.LongOperation.enableServerPushForThisTask(LongOperation.java:172)
      at c.p.t.e.LongOperation.start(LongOperation.java:117)
      at c.p.t.c.MyController.myExport(MyController.java:332)
```

That means that I am enabling ServerPush for the Desktop and in most cases this is done correctly. I am trying to figure out what might cause this to fail...
The exact error happens in org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.DesktopImpl.java (l.1510) inside the private boolean enableServerPush0(ServerPush sp, boolean enable) {...}.

```
public class DesktopImpl implements Desktop, DesktopCtrl, java.io.Serializable {
... 
private boolean enableServerPush0(ServerPush sp, boolean enable) {
        if (_sess == null)
            throw new IllegalStateException("Server push cannot be enabled in a working thread");

        final boolean serverPushAlreadyExists = _spush != null;

        if (serverPushAlreadyExists != enable) {
            final Integer icnt = (Integer) _sess.getAttribute(ATTR_PUSH_COUNT);
            int cnt = icnt != null ? icnt.intValue() : 0;
            if (enable) {
                if (Executions.getCurrent() == null)
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Server Push cannot be started without execution");
...
}
```

I know that I do not provide enough information for actual debugging my code. I would be grateful if someone could point me out to the right direction. What should I try? Any use cases that could result in Executions.getCurrent() becoming null?

Answer (score 0):

ZK wraps an AJAX request data into an [Execution](https://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/Execution.html) object and pass such object through the whole process of handling events.

An application server spawns a servlet thread for each AJAX request, so `Execution` is available in this thread. If you run a separate thread other than a servlet thread, then no execution is available. In such thread, if you want to update UI (call ZK component setter), you need to enable server and wait for an Execution. Please read [The Developer's reference / server push](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Server_Push/Synchronous_Tasks).

Comment: I am trying to enable Server by calling enableServerPush and the above situation and error happen during that process - I can't figure out a way to reproduce this issue, I have only seen it a couple of times in my log file of the application.

Comment: Do you call zk component API inside `Executions.activate(desktop);` and `deactivate()`?
Can you paste the stack trace including the line that causes the exception?

Comment: I am reviewing my code and inside my start() method (before the run()) I have the following code:

`if (Executions.getCurrent() != null) {
            this.desktopId = Executions.getCurrent().getDesktop().getId();
            this.desktopCache = ((WebAppCtrl) WebApps.getCurrent()).getDesktopCache(Sessions.getCurrent());
enableServerPushForThisTask();`

And the enableServerPushForThisTask() is:
`((DesktopCtrl) getDesktop()).enableServerPush(true, taskId);`

Should I activate() and deactivate() the desktop before and after my code?

Answer (score 0):

you should enable server push in a servlet thread, e.g. in a composer or ViewModel. In your long running thread, activate before you call zk component API.

```
Executions.activate(desktop);
//logic to update UI
label.setValue(message);
Executions.deactivate(desktop);
```